# Importing JSON via Angular service throws: Unexpected Token / error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've created a service that imports a JSON and uses it's information to fill an HTML template. I've done this before successfully with different apps. This time, I'm getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
at Object.parse (native)
```

I'm almost positive the issue is *not* with my JSON as I used a test JSON that had worked in another app of mine and I got the same error.

My relevant code:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('ClimbLog', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
  // Completely disable SCE
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

getClimblogs.js:

```
app.factory('getClimblogs', ['$http', function ($http) {
return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/exampleJSON.json')
        .success(function (data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController',['$scope', 'getClimblogs', function ($scope, getClimblogs){
getClimblogs.success(function (data) {
    $scope.climbLogs = data.climbs;
});
}]);
```

JSON:

```
{"climbs":[{
    "climbID":"xxxxxx",
    "date":"Aug. 10, 2015",
    "location":"Portland,ME",
    "routeName":"Trendsetter",
    "type":"Traditional",
    "grade":"5.10b",
    "partner":"Sarah Smokeshow",
    "challengeLevel":8,
    "time":6.05,
    "notes":"Finally got a chance to send this guy!",
    "photo": "https://photoUrl"
},

{
    "climbID":"yyyyyy",
    "date":"Aug. 10, 2015",
    "location":"Brunswick,ME",
    "routeName":"Poopmobile",
    "type":"Boulder",
    "grade":"V10",
    "partner":"Sarah Smokeshow",
    "challengeLevel":10,
    "time":4.05,
    "notes":"I'm beat..",
    "photo": "https://photoUrl"
}
]}
```

Comment: angular uses `JSON.parse` internally. try to do `JSON.parse(payload)` by hand to test if your payload is properly formatted.

Comment: even using a test json that is properly formatted (and worked in another app) is throwing the same error

Comment: If you navigate directly to http://localhost:8000/exampleJSON.json do you see a valid JSON?

Comment: yes. it's formatted like the JSON above. Not sure if that's okay? Here's a link to the same file uploaded to an AWS bucket https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-2#&bucket=randomdocs&prefix=

Comment: I was only thinking that the server was somehow changing the JSON. If that's not the case try to avoid using the service and call directly `$http.get` in your controller. `app.controller('MainController',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/exampleJSON.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.climbLogs = data.climbs;
});
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

I am a moron. I had a comment at the top of the JSON file.. it's habit of mine to label each file with a comment inside.

Once I got rid of that, it worked.